# Why does it matter that closures allow functions to access external variables that are in scope when the function is defined?

Tags: javascript

A dev asked me a question he heard somewhere which he said:

> Closures allow functions to
>
> 1. Access external variables that are in scope when the function is defined
> 2. Access external variables that are in scope when the function is called

The answer is when the function is defined. I am trying to wrap my head around:

1. Why this matters.
2. How would you ever know or test this.

My question is: How would one know that a closure has access to external variables in scope when defined if you can only console log when closures are called? I would like to see some code that proves this.

Second question is: if this is true that closures have access to external variables in scope, then what benefit does this give you and why does it matter?

Comment: Why the difference between "defined" and "called" matters and how you'd test that difference? Or what?

Comment: it lets you lock-in private lexical values, providing security with the ease of "psuedo-globals"

Comment: @dandavis "Security"…? Against what?

Comment: The second should probably be "…from where the function is called". It seems to be a reference to lexical scoping.

Comment: @deceze I understand what the difference between called and defined, but I don't know how you would know that a function has access before it is called and why that matters.

Comment: @dandavis I accept "type safety" or "encapsulation"; "security" is at best an overloaded term and at worst misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function makeCallback() {
    var foo = 'one';

    return function () {
        alert(foo);
    };
}

function bar(callback) {
    var foo = 'two';
    callback();
}

bar(makeCallback());
```

*This* is where the difference matters. If the function could access variables from the scope it's called in, this would alert "two". This is known as [*dynamic scoping*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope). But since Javascript uses lexical scoping, it actually alerts "one".

Comment: that makes sense. You might want to update the answer to make more sense.

Comment: I've removed that potential point of confusion. Now it might be confusing because closures are confusing, but oh well… ;)